# Regex pattern does not support # symbol

Tags: regex, nginx

I use regex in Nginx configs to capture file urls but if the file URL contains the # symbol, regex pattern will not capture it.

Here is the part of nginx config.

```
location ~ ^/p/(?<secure>[\w\-=]+,\d+),(?<user>[^/]+)(?<file>/.*)$ {

}
```

An example file URL causing the error because it has # symbol in it.

```
http://mydomain.com/p/KPFHELPFAQrc3rUPIUS7Cg,1401267921,1/4962/Ubuntu#6 (DVD-ISO)/Ubuntu-12-04.iso
```

Comment: I believe that the problem is that the part after # is not passed to server, so the server actually gets request for `http://mydomain.com/p/KPFHELPFAQrc3rUPIUS7Cg,1401267921,1/4962/Ubuntu` url. More about fragment urls: [6 Things You Should Know About Fragment URLs](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov is right, the browser does not send # or anything after it as part of the request.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I see, I was looking  for a way to fix this by replacing # with a special set of characters (ex: 0__0 ) using PHP and then again after receiving the request replace 0__0 with # in nginx configs using rewrite. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Please post the comment as the answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `#` to `%23` in url:

```
http://mydomain.com/p/KPFHELPFAQrc3rUPIUS7Cg,1401267921,1/4962/Ubuntu%236 (DVD-ISO)/Ubuntu-12-04.iso
```

Here is complete list of [URL Escape Characters](http://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters)